# Zipping many files with JSZip is crashing

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, zip, jszip

I am having a problem using JSZip to zip files and any help is greatly appreciated.

Basically, I am working on an application where users can upload a directory containing multiple files. An individual file will never be more than 2GB and most are much smaller (~10MB), but there can be thousands of files in a directory so the total size could be 20GB+.What I want to do is use JSZip to zip the files into a single zip file and then upload that single zip file to AWS S3. The problem is, my browser is crashing when I start testing with a larger number of files. When I tried with a directory containing 1000 files for a total size of ~8GB, my browser crashes and I see a `Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED` error. This error happens before I make it to the uploading step.

I am letting users upload files with a HTML input and saving the file in memory before the zipping and uploading happens. Here is the code I'm using to zip the files:

```
        const zip = new JSZip();

        files.forEach((file) => {
            zip.file(file.name, file)
        });

        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
            .then((content) => uploadToS3(content))
```

It seems like storing the files and the zip in memory is too much for my machine to handle and I'm sure some of my users will have smaller machines than I do. Any ideas on how I can implement this would be very helpful.

Thanks!